# Sort array by date gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

This will sound as an easy problem but I spent my Sunday trying to figure out what's wrong with my implementation described below so I am posting it to SO as a last resort.

I have a javascript application that receives data structures from a server. The server side sends the data unsorted for performance reasons.

Here is a snippet of the the javascript code receiving data:

```
    var seriesRawDataArray = ko.observableArray();
    ...
    analyticscontext.series(seriesRawDataArray).done(function () {
        renderSeries();
    });
```

The `analyticscontext` module queries the data using ajax:

```
function series(seriesData) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/api/analytics/series",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            return seriesData(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The `renderSeries` performs a sort on the data before rendering it:

```
    // Sort the data by date using moment.js
    seriesRawDataArray.sort(function (left, right) {
        var leftDate = moment.utc(left.timeStamp);
        var rightDate = moment.utc(right.timeStamp);
        var diff = leftDate.diff(rightDate);
        return diff > 0;
    });
```

**PROBLEM**

Here is a data sample I receive from my server:
[image]

Notice the unsorted items at the end.
the `seriesRawDataArray.sort` seem to have no effect on the original array which does not get sorted no matter what I change in the sorting method. The output is always:

[image]

Notice the unsorted elements here. 
The libraries I am using and the data is definitely not the problem as this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3gzpp7h/) works just fine!
Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @kostik I am using a knockout sort which takes care of that. The problem is spotted in the answer below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 174, accepted):

### short answer

You should return the difference between the two dates, not a boolean:

```
// sort the data by date using moment.js
seriesRawDataArray.sort(function (left, right) {
    return moment.utc(left.timeStamp).diff(moment.utc(right.timeStamp))
});
```

### why

[`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects a negative, zero, or positive value to be returned. Generally, you'll write a sort function like this:

```
yourArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a < b) {            // a comes first
        return -1
    } else if (b < a) {     // b comes first
        return 1
    } else {                // equal, so order is irrelevant
        return 0            // note: sort is not necessarily stable in JS
    }
})
```

<sup>The anonymous function passed to sort serves as the comparator for the native implementation of the sort function.</sup>

However, your negative value doesn't have to be `-1` and your positive value doesn't have to be `+1`. Therefore, when sorting numbers, you can instead use the shortcut:

```
yourArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b
})
```

In JavaScript, subtracting two dates coerces them both into numbers, which is why we could use `return moment.utc(left.timeStamp).diff(moment.utc(right.timeStamp))`

<sup>(instead of direct subtraction `-`, this method uses [`moment.prototype.diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) from the `moment.js` library)</sup>

**However**, in your code, you returned `diff > 0`, which can be either `true` or `false`. Because of type coercion, JavScript will read `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`. This means your sort function will never return `-1`. Therefore, your elements will not be sorted correctly.

Comment: Note that you may need to filter out values that are not valid.  `if(a._isValid && b._isValid)` when sorting Moment Js dates.

Comment: Any reason why `.utc` is needed?

Answer (score 14):

```
let sortedDates = dates.sort(function(a, b){
  return moment(b).format('X')-moment(a).format('X')
});
```

Since moment can format valid dates the best way is to use the sort method javascript, so when formatting the date to timestamp, basically you sort by number.

References:

http://www.momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works for any moment date format

```
let original = ['Fri May 12 2023', 'Sat May 13 2023', 'Wed May 03 2023', 'Thu May 04 2023', 'Fri May 05 2023', 'Sat May 06 2023', 'Sun May 14 2023']   
const sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a.diff(b))
 //   ['Wed May 03 2023', 'Thu May 04 2023', 'Fri May 05 2023', 'Sat May 06 2023', 'Fri May 12 2023', 'Sat May 13 2023', 'Sun May 14 2023']
```

`diff` takes the usual moment input, e.g. a date-formatted string.

You can see more about this here https://gist.github.com/onildoaguiar/6cf7dbf9e0f0b8684eb5b0977b40c5ad