# Sum objects with similar key values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects like so:

```
var objects = [{a:'b',c:'d',count:1},{a:'b',c:'d',count:2},{a:'y',c:'d',count:4}]
```

I want to sum all the counts that have the same `a` and `b` values to make something like so:

```
{a:'b',c:'d',count:3},{a:'y',c:'d',count:4}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are the variables you need to check always a and c ?

Comment: Yes they are always `a` and `c`.

Comment: if one of these answers worked for you please remember to select it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that case, you could easily group your objects by the value of a + b:

```
var objects = [{a:'b',c:'d',count:1},{a:'b',c:'d',count:2},{a:'y',c:'d',count:4}]


function getId(obj){ // how to group the objects
    return obj.a + '|'+ obj.c
}


var groups = {};

for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){ // for each obj
    var id = getId(objects[i])  // get id
    if(groups.hasOwnProperty(id)){ // if group is already created, add count
        groups[id].count += objects[i].count         
    }else{ // else create group with same values
        groups[id] = {a:objects[i].a, c: objects[i].c, count:objects[i].count}
    }
}

console.log(groups) // you can then change the groups to an array if you want
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a great library called [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/) which is wonderful for composing complicated data manipulation:

```
var R = require('ramda'); // Edit: you can also use a script tag if you're working in the browser. see http://ramdajs.com/

// Concatenate the values for a & c so that we group by values
var groups = R.groupBy(R.converge(R.concat, R.prop('a'), R.prop('c')), objects);

// We just want the grouped arrays, not the concatenated keys
groups = R.values(groups);

var aggregateCounts = R.compose(R.sum, R.pluck('count'));

groups = groups.map(function(group) {
  return {
    a: group[0].a,
    c: group[0].c,
    count: aggregateCounts(group)
  };
});
```

Comment: This requires the poster to use require.  A pure javascript solution might be better

Comment: My mistake, I'm used to using node.  as you can see on the homepage ramda works just fine in the browser:http://ramdajs.com/

i would argue a pure javascript, or at least the solutions above is _not_ better because it's much harder to read. there's a reason utility libraries exist; the same reason people are allowed to use jquery in their DOM manipulation answers

Comment: I'd have to disagree. This solution is much more difficult to read, and not just because I didn't write it. It requires knowledge of the `ramda` library and it's really not much more concise. It's probably also less efficient, if I had to guess, because of all the function calls.

Comment: considering v8 does function inlining the overhead you're going to see with this is minimal. perhaps it's less readable to someone unfamiliar with ramda, but I'd suggest to OP to maybe take the time and learn ramda if he/she has a lot of data manipulation like this, because it really does make the code more self descriptive and easy to read IMO. doesn't have to use it or accept it but that's my answer :)

Comment: Ramda does look like a useful library, but most people will probably learn Lo-dash or underscore instead (despite what the front page says).

Comment: I use it in my production code. Despite the learning curve, the payback in readability, concision, and reduction in needed brainpower to read object/array manipulation code like the above is astounding. I would highly recommend it to anyone

Comment: With Ramda, `R.mergeWith(R.add, objA, objB)` is enough for two objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the `objects` array, then create a new array by pushing the objects as `a` and `c` change:

```js
var objects = [{a:'b',c:'d',count:1},{a:'y',c:'d',count:4},{a:'b',c:'d',count:2}],
    newobj = [];
    
objects.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.a+a.c > b.a+b.c ?  1 :
         a.a+a.c < b.a+b.c ? -1 :
         0;
});

for(var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++) {
  if(i === 0 || objects[i].a !== objects[i-1].a || objects[i].b !== objects[i-1].b) {
    newobj.push({a: objects[i].a, c: objects[i].c, count: objects[i].count});
  }
  else {
    newobj[newobj.length-1].count+= objects[i].count;
  }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(newobj));
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output.

Comment: @royhowie, I don't understand.  This produces the same output as your code.

Comment: my console reads: `[{a:"b",c:"d",count:1},{a:"y",c:"d",count:4},{a:"b",c:"d",count:2}]`, (the same thing as `objects`).

Comment: Hmm, mine shows the same as yours using Chrome.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Safari Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18). I just checked in Chrome and it does work, however.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say it has to do with `return a.a+a.c > b.a+b.c;`. You should really write that as `return (a.a + a.c) > (b.a + b.c);`. Safari is probably reading it as `return a.a + (a.c > b.a) + b.a;`, which I'm sure was not your intention.

Comment: It was in the `sort` function.  Now updated.  I would have never thought to check in Safari.  Thanks again.

Comment: You [need to return -1, 0, or 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28013152/2476755) in the sort function. Returning just -1 or 1 may not properly sort.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to check for equality, but it *is* best practice from what I'm reading.  Now updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just group them by the keys:

```
var aggregate = function (objects) {
    var map = {}; // map to store data
    var a = [];   // temporary array to hold the objects
    objects.forEach(function (d) {
        var key = d.a > d.c ? String(d.c) + d.a : String(d.a) + d.c;
        // if {a:2,c:3} is the same as {c:2,a:3}, use the above,
        // otherwise, just use key = String(d.a) + String(d.c);
        map[key] = (map[key] || 0) + d.count;
    })
    // e.g., key === "bd"
    for (var key in map) {
        // so split it into ["b", "d"]
        var k = key.toString().split("");
        // and push it to the temp array as the appropriate object
        a.push({ a: k[0], c: k[1], count: map[key] });
    }
    return a;
}

var objects = [{a:'b',c:'d',count:1},{a:'b',c:'d',count:2},{a:'y',c:'d',count:4}];
console.log(aggregate(objects));
// [{a:"b",c:"d",count:3},{a:"d",c:"y",count:4}]
```