# Get the minimum and maximum dates from JSON

Tags: javascript

There JSON:

```
[{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":38},{"source":"2016-11-01","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-03","sourcecount":30}]
```

As in JavaScript to get the maximum and minimum date of it?

Comment: So Your JSON only have two objects

Comment: Either sort this array by dates and take first and last  value (if array size is small), or iterate and keep comparing against smallest and largest value. Give it a try!

Comment: Iterate over them.  Consider `.forEach()`.

Comment: Loop through them and  extract dates and then sort it out...this could be of help to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013045/sort-array-by-date-gives-unexpected-results

Comment: `new Date(Math.max(...(arr.map(e => new Date(e.source))))).toISOString().split('T')[0]`

Comment: The most efficient solution is a single iteration over the array. Sorting is expensive and reorders the array which might not be desirable. Mapping creates unnecessary objects in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":38},{"source":"2016-11-01","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-03","sourcecount":30}];

var max = null;
var min = null;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var current = array[i];
  if (max === null || current.source > max.source) {
    max = current;
  }
  if (min === null || current.source < min.source) {
    min = current;
  }
}

document.getElementById('maxResult').innerHTML = max.source;
document.getElementById('minResult').innerHTML = min.source;
```

```html
Max: <span id="maxResult"></span><br/ >
Min: <span id="minResult"></span>
```

Comment: what if i need the value in at this date range?

Comment: max.value and min.value.

Comment: any is okey or both also fine. of sourcecount

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, provided your date format is "yyyy-MM-dd".

Convert the date string to dateKey. which always follow the ascending order as the dates proceed. 20160101(Jan 1st) is always less than 20161231(Dec 31st).

Keeping that in mind, just convert the dates to dateKey and map dateKeys to the object and just extract the max and min of the dateKeys and return the actual date.

```js
var datesArray = [{
  "source": "2016-11-02",
  "sourcecount": 38
}, {
  "source": "2016-11-10",
  "sourcecount": 30
}, {
  "source": "2016-11-31",
  "sourcecount": 38
}, {
  "source": "2016-01-01",
  "sourcecount": 30
}];

var newObject = {};
var dates = datesArray.map(function(obj) {
  var regEx = new RegExp(/-/g);
  //Convert date to dateKey
  var dateKey = parseInt(obj.source.replace(regEx, ""), 10)
  newObject[dateKey] = obj;
  return dateKey;
});

console.log("Max", newObject[Math.max(...dates)].source);
console.log("Min", newObject[Math.min(...dates)].source);
```

Comment: Nice use of spread operator. I'd use an arrow function for `.map` too.

Answer (score 1):

The good thing is, your date is in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format already. You can just simply do this,

```
var data = [{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":38},{"source":"2016-11-01","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-03","sourcecount":30}];

var dateArr = data.map(function(v) {
  return new Date(v.source);
});

// Sort the date
dateArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.getTime() - b.getTime();
  // OR `return a - b`
});

// The highest date is in the very last of array
var highestDate = dateArr[dateArr.length - 1];

// The lowest is in the very first..
var lowestDate = dateArr[0];
```

Or you prefer to have your original object instead, then you can do,

```
var data = [{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":38},{"source":"2016-11-01","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-03","sourcecount":30}];

data.sort(function(a,b) {
  var date1 = (new Date(a.source));
  var date2 = (new Date(b.source));
  return date1 - date2;
});

// highest date is '2016-11-03'
var highestDate = data[data.length - 1].source

// lowest date is '2016-11-01'
var lowestDate = data[0].source
```

Comment: I would prefer the first one. Thanks TIL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = [{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":38},{"source":"2016-11-01","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-02","sourcecount":30},{"source":"2016-11-03","sourcecount":30}]
function compare(a,b) {
   if (new Date(a.source) < new Date(b.source))
     return -1;
   if (new Date(a.source) > new Date(b.source))
     return 1;
   return 0;
}
data = data.sort(compare);
var minDate = data[0].source;
var maxDate = data[data.length - 1].source;
```

Comment: Performance wise, it is not efficient. `sort` is `o(nlogn)`, but you can find min and max just by iterating through the array in `o(n)`.