# how to get min or max dates from a list of dates using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, maxdate

I want to have the max date from the list of dates given in the **handleClick** function.
How to find the max date from the list of dates using **moment.js**?

I have the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

class Getdate extends Component
{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       dates = []
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
     this.state.dates = ['2017-11-12', '2017-10-22', '2015-01-10', '2018-01-01', '2014-10-10'];
     console.log(this.state.dates);
  }
  render{
    return (
     <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get Max Date</button>
    )
  }
}
export default Getdate
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can use [moment.max](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/max/) function :

```
let moments = this.state.dates.map(d => moment(d)),
    maxDate = moment.max(moments)
```

Comment: More concise is `this.state.dates.map( moment )`

Comment: @DuncanThacker, no, don't use that concise form because it will send extra params to `moment` and result in a **parse error**.

Comment: @Jimmy why would it send extra params? `(d => moment(d))` and `(moment)` are equivalent.
It's like doing `['abc','bcd'].map(x => console.log(x))` or `['abc','bcd'].map(console.log)` they are the same, aren't they?

Comment: @Aquazi The "extra params" I am referring to is the arguments of the `map` function. Here's a fiddle to showcase the error: https://jsfiddle.net/3qufbh5k/

The error is caused by the second `map(...)` argument, the index, which causes an error because `moment(...)` expects a string format as second parameter

Comment: **Beware** that if you happen to pass an empty list into `moment.max`, it erroneously returns the current date rather than something more reasonable like `undefined`.

Comment: @Jimmy how can I get max time only, from array of date-timestamp irrespective of date?

Comment: @FaizanSaiyed You can format by time to find the max: https://jsfiddle.net/IliasDeros/p2daxks1/18/

Answer (score -3):

Sort them with a custom compartor, then select the first one (or last, try it out);

```
   array.sort(function(d1, d2) {
       return moment(d1).isBefore(moment(d2));
        });
```

Comment: While this looks like it would work, note that `sort` expects _numeric_ return values from the compare function and not _boolean_. See [Sort array by date gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013045/sort-array-by-date-gives-unexpected-results)